# firebird alter trigger into stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, firebird

How can i alter a trigger into store proceure?, i have this code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PESTADOTRIGGER (
    disparador varchar(40),
    estado integer)
as
declare variable cadena varchar(500);
begin

    if (:estado = 1) then
    begin
        cadena = 'ALTER TRIGGER ' || :disparador ||  ' ACTIVE';
        EXECUTE STATEMENT :CADENA  WITH AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION;
    END
    ELSE
    begin 
        cadena = 'ALTER TRIGGER ' || :disparador ||  ' INACTIVE';
        EXECUTE STATEMENT :CADENA  WITH AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION;
    END

end
```

when execute the stored procedure show an message:

> unsuccessful metadata update modify trigger failed no peermission for
>   control acess to table

I am running the procedure with the SYSDBA user, but it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your database user. A trigger can be changed by the creator, the SYSDBA user and other users with superuser permissions.

Try to execute your stored procedure as SYSDBA user.

**EDIT** 
This is my test database.

```
/******************************************************************************/
/****        Generated by IBExpert 2015.9.28.1 08.10.2015 19:06:46         ****/
/******************************************************************************/

SET SQL DIALECT 3;

SET NAMES UTF8;

CREATE DATABASE '127.0.0.1:C:\DB\Test.FDB'
USER 'SYSDBA' PASSWORD 'masterkey'
PAGE_SIZE 16384
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATION UTF8;



/******************************************************************************/
/****                              Generators                              ****/
/******************************************************************************/

CREATE GENERATOR GEN_TEST_ID;
SET GENERATOR GEN_TEST_ID TO 0;



/******************************************************************************/
/****                          Stored procedures                           ****/
/******************************************************************************/



SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE PROCEDURE PESTADOTRIGGER (
    DISPARADOR VARCHAR(40),
    ESTADO INTEGER)
AS
BEGIN
  EXIT;
END^






SET TERM ; ^



/******************************************************************************/
/****                                Tables                                ****/
/******************************************************************************/



CREATE TABLE TEST (
    ID   BIGINT NOT NULL,
    TXT  VARCHAR(50)
);




/******************************************************************************/
/****                             Primary keys                             ****/
/******************************************************************************/

ALTER TABLE TEST ADD PRIMARY KEY (ID);


/******************************************************************************/
/****                               Triggers                               ****/
/******************************************************************************/



SET TERM ^ ;



/******************************************************************************/
/****                         Triggers for tables                          ****/
/******************************************************************************/



/* Trigger: TEST_BI */
CREATE TRIGGER TEST_BI FOR TEST
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
as
begin
  if (new.ID is null) then
    new.ID = gen_id(GEN_TEST_ID,1);
end
^


/* Trigger: TEST_TRIGGER */
CREATE TRIGGER TEST_TRIGGER FOR TEST
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS
begin
  if (new.TXT='ABC') then
  begin
    new.TXT='CBA';
  end
end
^

SET TERM ; ^



/******************************************************************************/
/****                          Stored procedures                           ****/
/******************************************************************************/



SET TERM ^ ;

ALTER PROCEDURE PESTADOTRIGGER (
    DISPARADOR VARCHAR(40),
    ESTADO INTEGER)
AS
declare variable cadena varchar(500);
begin

    if (:estado = 1) then
    begin
        cadena = 'ALTER TRIGGER ' || :disparador ||  ' ACTIVE';
        EXECUTE STATEMENT :CADENA  WITH AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION;
    END
    ELSE
    begin 
        cadena = 'ALTER TRIGGER ' || :disparador ||  ' INACTIVE';
        EXECUTE STATEMENT :CADENA  WITH AUTONOMOUS TRANSACTION;
    END

end^



SET TERM ; ^
```

Comment: You really have a permission problem. I just tested the procedure in a test database and it worked fine. Please dopple check your user and the permissions.

Comment: The following SQL deactivates the trigger TEST_TRIGGER: execute procedure PESTADOTRIGGER('TEST_TRIGGER', 0)